# Clients website shows blank page

Tags: css

For some reason, [my client's website](http://tedxkarachi.pk/) is blank. After some debugging, I realized that all of the colors have been changed to #FFF. What would be the best way to recover the site?

Method #1
I install the theme again.

Method #2
I upload the css file again

Please guide me.

Comment: Compare your stylesheet before uploading

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to check if the font were made White by editing the CSS or using Customizer, and accordingly restoring the CSS or the Entire theme is suggested.

Also try changing the theme to a default one and then back to this one.

Answer (score 1):

This should be do with the following reason

1. css loaded partially.
2. conflict Js or missing.
3. some function not works not server which fire the fatal error if this exists then you need to change on you wp-config.php file which is located at server:

change this code :

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

which show you actual error.